# Android studio library project

Tags: android, android-studio

I think it might be useful to create small library projects these would be standalone components that would be used in my main projects (plural). For example they would be custom or compound views that I would generally use in all of my projects.

However in Android Studio it does not seem possible to just create a library project. Instead I have to create a New Project and then create a library project. But instead I was hoping I could create a New Project and then import the library projects that I had previously created.

Is there any solution for this approach or am I misunderstanding how to use library modules ?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to look into creating a (local or remote) maven repo to act as a source for library projects that have been published it to it.  What you're asking is pretty broad, though, so I wouldn't expect to get a complete list of instructions here.

Answer (score 0):

you can do what you want by : either distribute your library (on jcenter for example). The problem is this will be a public library so anyone could potentially use it ; or create your library in a git project for example and add this repository in your main project

Answer (score 0):

I would just pick a main project (or create a test project) you would like to test your library with.  The library is just a module as far as Android Studio goes.  Then you can checkout the module as an external/remote in source control for your other projects.